# Software for monitoring web sites accessed via shared wireless connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, monitoring

I have shared my Internet connection to my neighbour using wireless network. Now I want to know what web sites he/she is accessing through my Internet connection.

Please provide a list of free software that we can use to do this.

Comment: Please let us know how you're sharing it.  Router? Through your PC?

Comment: Invasion of privacy much? I also share my internet with my neighbor and I could care less as long as it's not draining my bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless router might be able to keep an activity log.

Just logon to it, using an address such as http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.1.1, and see if has such an option.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware used to provide the shared internet connection, you may be able to monitor the traffic from the router itself. If the router doesn't have this capability (not a common function in consumer devices) then you may be able to load [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) onto the router which will provide that functionality.

You may also be able to setup a proxy which will also trap that kind of information but the setup and use of a proxy may be more involved than you want just to track your neighbor's websites.

DNS services like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) can be configured to track some of this type of information as well but that would be more of a catch-all instead of computer specific set of information.